# when field on child object is updated to have a value, change field on parent to be null trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger, after-trigger

working on this trigger for 2 custom objects in a master-detail relationship, rep is the parent, role history is the child. the `insert` part works perfectly, just am struggling with the `update` portion. i've included the entire code in case my previous map needs to be used. when there is an existing role history record, when the user updates the "End Date" field on role history object to have any value (making it not null), it needs to set the "Rep Type" field on the rep object to null. Here is my code:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the End_Date__c to the query on parentsRep Map.

`parentReps = new Map<Id, Rep__c>([SELECT Id, Rep_Type__c, (SELECT Id, Type__c, End_Date__c  FROM Role_Histories__r WHERE End_Date__c = null ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1) FROM Rep__c WHERE Id IN :listIds]);`

RoleHistoryAfterTrigger: execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: System.SObjectException: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Role_History__c.End_Date__c Trigger.RoleHistoryAfterTrigger: line 37, column 1

The error is telling you what is the issue, every time you come across this issue check if the query has the needed fields.

Comment: Which kind of field is Rep_Type__c? is a picklist field? if it's a picklist, look for the  Picklist Options if Restrict picklist to the values defined in the value set is checked. @testing

Comment: It's a required field?

Comment: reps.Rep_Type__c = ''; instead of null

Comment: i think i finally got it to work?? i updated the original question so you can see the code i used. however the only thing i'm confused by is i have to refresh the page like 4 times for the field to show as null? no idea why there's such a delay